# Powershell command to backup a SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Is there a PowerShell command that will execute a backup of all databases on a server?

Alternatively, can I call a stored proc from PowerShell (that will execute the backup)?

Comment: It will be nice to know how the scripts will perform in this scenario. Any reason why would you prefer this than the native way of backing up a SQL Server DB?

Comment: What is the native way of backing up a SQL Server DB? Currently I open up SSMS and run a stored proc that backs up all the DB's into a directory. Then I run a powershell script that moves all of this to a backup location. My intention is to do this in one step from Powershell instead of 2 steps.

Answer (score 9):

if you are running sql server 2008 you have powershell bindings. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281847.aspx)

SQL Server 2008 powershell has a cmdlet [invoke-sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, there are some pre-requisites you need to have installed (namely the [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Management Objects Collectio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=D09C1D60-A13C-4479-9B91-9E8B9D835CDC&displaylang=en)n) and theres quite alot of powersehll code needed to do it, however there are a number of articles out there that have it allready done for you. I have used [this method](http://monadblog.blogspot.com/2006/07/back-up-sql-server-database-with-sql.html) successfully in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ADO.NET from PowerShell to execute a stored proc..

See [this example](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/31149-executing-stored-procedure-powershell.html).

Comment: Good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There's functions for PowerShell-based SQL Server database backups included in the CodePlex project [SQL Server PowerShell Extensions](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com) (SQLPSX). Take look at Invoke-SqlBackup or if you want to implement a full backup and maintenance routine take a look at the SQLMaint module.